# Formatting Database Schema From SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Ok I ve been asked to generate a schema for a database that contains 20+ tables

I ve used SQLServer Management studio to extract out the database schema but cannot export it into word

If I copy it as a diagram the tables are too small

Does anyone know how to extract the schema from a sql server database so that it is presentable to a project manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create more than one database diagram, each containing part of the schema. Make those small enough to see.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Visio you can use the reverse engineer functionality to generate a schema diagram of your database which you can then format to make look presentable.  If required this will then paste nicely into word.

More information [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614)

Comment: I've used this many times and as long as you don't need detail this works great.  If you need it to get more in depth beyond the basic table/relationship structure, Visio is insufficient.

Comment: That's true but the database desiner is not in all versions of Visio. If I remember correctly you need the Visio 2003 for Enterprise Architects or Visio 2007 Professional version. If you can do it through, Visio is a great tool for database diagram reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply take a screen shot of the database diagrams...