# Database Schema Diagram From SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Is Visio the only way here??

I saw another stackoverflow question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474/database-schema-diagram-design-tool

And whilst Sql Designer is nice I dont want to draw all the tables by hand - Is there any way to short circut this and upload SQL DDL and it generates the tables in a diagram??

Comment: Just keep with your existing question.

Comment: You just asked this. If you have follow-up questions, add them as comments to the answers, or comments/edits on your own post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976982/formatting-database-schema-from-sql-server

Answer (score 8):

MS SQL Server has built - in Data Schema diagramming tool (in the SQL Server Management Studio).  Just right click on the database diagrams node in the tree under the database you want to create a schema from... Once you have an empty diagram object, you can even create actual database tables directly on the diagram

Comment: It will also create a diagram for any or all existing tables.

Comment: +1 for saving me a lot of time. It works with SSMS 2008 **Express**, too.

Answer (score 2):

MS Visio has a function to generate a database diagram from an existing database. For Vision 2008 go to Tools->Add-Ons->Visio Extras->Database Wizard. I used it a few years ago, but have no sql server at hand to test it right now.

EDIT: Just saw that you specifically asked for SQL Designer. Have a look at the [manual](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/wiki/Manual).

> Basics
>
> The application allows you to:
>
> ...
>
> 6. Import DB schemas