# Quickie ERD maker

Tags: erd

I've been using Visio to make ERD's, but I have a boatload of resource-hogging things running right now and wondered if there weren't something very light I could use instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a python3 package that does database inspection. It includes a tool, that creates ER diagrams from the database schema. You can check it here: http://code.google.com/p/fathom/ and it also documents how to generate a diagram: http://code.google.com/p/fathom/wiki/Manual#fathom2graphviz

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Database, it may have one built in. If you're on a Microsoft stack, SQL server has an ERD tool built in.

Also check out [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977012/database-schema-diagram-from-sql-server)